# Make Calculated Table of Stops that looks at both Pickup and Delivery Stop on an Order

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns, logistics

I do Power BI for a logistics company. We want to show performance by stop location. The data is currently a table of all orders by Order ID, so -- ID, Rev $, Pickup Stop, Delivery Stop. Everything is a 2-stop load, fortunately.

What I am struggling with is building a calculated table that looks at the Pickup Stop AND the Delivery Stop at the same time while ALSO respecting filters set on the page. I would like the stops table to say something like: Stop Location, X Pickups, $X Pickup Revenue, X Deliveries, $X Delivery Revenue.

How would I go about this? I've tried a number of approaches but every time it either misses filters or can only handle one stop at a time.

Thanks!

**Current Data**
**call it Orders**
[image: Current Data, call it Orders]

**The calculated table I'm trying to make**
**call it Stops**
[image: The calculated table I'm trying to make, call it Stops]

Comment: Your two tables are identical.  Making it quite difficult to know what you want.

Comment: Apologies. I struggled with the formatting of images in the question publisher. Should be corrected now.

Comment: How would your output look if there were multiple delivery/pickups per Stop?  Multiple `X`'s?  Something Else?

Comment: They'd be summary values.  I had some success by creating two calculated tables like so, then joining them at Pickup/Delivery Stops. However I don't know how to join to the Orders table and still respect slicers/filters.                                                                Pickup Stops = summarize(Orders, Orders[Pickup Stop], "Outbound Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[Order ID]), "Outbound Revenue", sum(Orders[Total Revenue]))

Delivery Stops = summarize(Orders, Orders[Delivery Stop], "Inbound Orders", DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[Order ID]), "Inbound Revenue", sum(Orders[Total Revenue]))

Answer (score 0):

One method of creating your **Stops**, given your **Orders** is by using Power Query, accessed via `Queries=>Transform Data` on the Power BI Home Tab.

The `Table.Group` function is where the magic happens. Unfortunately, it needs to be done by coding in the Advanced Editor, as the UI does not provide for these custom aggregations.

- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- The first three lines should be replaced by whatever you are reading in your own **Orders** table with.
- Paste the rest of M Code below in place of what is below your setup lines in your own query
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    //Input data and set datatypes
    //These lines should be replaced with whatever you need to 
    //set up your data table
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bYzBCoMwEER/Zck5BxPRu1RaLJaW6qEQPIS4tEExoonQv+/a0oLQyw5vZnaUYuepxQmKnHFWO697uOKCQ0DiizVdGKHybiTKsbcLTs8PN1wxIZMooiR938z3evCawyFbKczeDhzq268qyBZpsg23f9+qJF+Skuwe1ui741CU/2djsmO53lJ3SFsth/3aPWrTzY7Kp4o1zQs=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t, Column4 = _t]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    dataSource = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"Order ID", Int64.Type}, {"Total Revenue", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Pickup Stop", type text}, {"Delivery Stop", type text}}),

    //Unpivot to get single column of Stops
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(dataSource, {"Order ID", "Total Revenue"}, "Attribute", "Stop"),

    //Group by stop and do the aggregations
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Stop"}, {
        {"Orders Picked Up", (t)=> List.Count(List.Select(t[Attribute], each _ = "Pickup Stop" )), Int64.Type},
        {"Total Revenue Picked Up", (t)=> List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Attribute]="Pickup Stop")[Total Revenue]), type number},
        {"Orders Delivered", (t)=> List.Count(List.Select(t[Attribute], each _ = "Delivery Stop" )), Int64.Type},
        {"Total Revenue Delivered", (t)=> List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Attribute]="Delivery Stop")[Total Revenue]), type number}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Orders**
[image]

**Stops**
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm following your instructions but I don't have any experience with Power Query here to plug in the original source correctly. Sounds like I need to study PQ from scratch if I intend to go that route.

Comment: @EvanSwanzy  If you have your table in Power BI, in your **Orders** format, select the Transform option should open PQ.  Then select Home=>Advanced Editor and you should be able to see the PQ code.  Then you should be able to add the `unpivot` and `group` code at that point. But familiarize yourself with how it works to get the syntax to merge properly with the previous code.